# need to find rank of each row across 20000 rows, apply function taking too long

Tags: r, apply

Please help with following:

```
# create sequence of numbers
a<-matrix(0:16384,1,16385)
# fill matrix with this same sequence across 20,000 rows
b<-matrix(a,20000,ncol(a),byrow=T)
# find rank of every element, by row
c<-t(apply(b,1, function(x) rank(x, ties.method="first")))
```

This is just a sample, b will have a random sequence.

Here is an example of the output:
If b had this (2 rows by 3 columns for now) :

```
1 5 10
2 1 6
```

I want this to be in my output:

```
1 2 3
2 1 3
```

It's taking a very long time to process. Please, please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Write your code in C

Comment: @Alex oh no, no idea how to do that. can you show me how if possible? Rcpp?

Comment: would data.table help by any chance?

Comment: Hi, I found rowranks in matrixStats package, however, the ties.method can only be min, max or average. I need to use ties.method="first". PLEASE HELP.

Comment: `system.time(t(apply(b,1, function(x) rank(x, ties.method="first"))))` takes 1.7sec of system time and 28 sec of elapsed time on my server. On my standard laptop, using `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` it takes 59 seconds... that's really not that long. But, if you want it to be faster, write it in C

Comment: It _is_ a 1.2 Gb, 20,000 x 16,385, 327,700,000 element matrix, so 45 seconds of elapsed time (on my laptop) to read, process, and write that is not all that bad. If you're doing a lot with with matrices this big, write your code in C++ (via `Rcpp`), or try Julia if you're adventurous.

Comment: With that many columns, you can save a few seconds very easily by replacing `rank` with `frank` from `data.table`.

Comment: @Alex no idea how to write in C, or use Rcpp

Comment: @Jota I tried your function, any potential there?

Comment: the trouble is it can go up to 300k rows.....

Comment: @charliealpha You've asked how to speed up the code. All the commentators have said "hey, it's a **big** matrix. R is only so fast." The best option is to *deal with the fact that it takes a minute*, which really is not that long. The other options are to (1) get a faster computer and (2) write the code in a faster language (ie C/C++).... This is not a programming service. No one is going to write your C/C++ code for you. Either learn to write it yourself or settle for the R runtime.

Comment: Just to follow up on the suggestion from @Jota. Using `frank` from `data.table` takes about 1/3 of the time compared to using `rank`, if you don't want to go the Rcpp way. That's a lot of saved time by adding a single letter (and a package)